# Entity Core 2.0.3 Exception: must be reducible node

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to convert the following sql query to EF

sql Query

```
Select  Sum([KiloWatt]) as 'Sum',
    Min([KiloWatt]) as 'Min',
    Max([KiloWatt]) as 'Max',
    Sum([KiloWatt])/COUNT([KiloWatt]) as 'Average',
    CONVERT(date, [DateTime]) 
from OneHourElectricitys 
where [DateTime] < SYSDATETIME()
group by CONVERT(date, [DateTime])
```

EF Code

```
var analytics = await _analyticsRepository.Query().Where(x => x.DateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Today).Days < 0)
                                                  .GroupBy(x => x.DateTime.Date)
                                                  .Select(x => new 
                                                    { DateTime = x.Key, 
                                                      Max = x.Max(y => y.KiloWatt),
                                                      Min = x.Min(y => y.KiloWatt),
                                                      Avg = x.Sum(y => y.KiloWatt)/ x.Count(),
                                                      Sum = x.Sum(y => y.KiloWatt)
                                                    })
                                                  .ToListAsync();
```

Stack Trace :-

> System.ArgumentException: must be reducible node
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceAndCheck()
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceExtensions()

Am I doing coming wrong?

-- Update --

The following 2 EF queries run fine but combining them gives the error.

```
var analytics = await _analyticsRepository.Query().Where(x => x.DateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Today).Days < 0)

var analytics = await _analyticsRepository.Query().GroupBy(x => x.DateTime.Date)
                                              .Select(x => new 
                                                { DateTime = x.Key, 
                                                  Max = x.Max(y => y.KiloWatt),
                                                  Min = x.Min(y => y.KiloWatt),
                                                  Avg = x.Sum(y => y.KiloWatt)/ x.Count(),
                                                  Sum = x.Sum(y => y.KiloWatt)
                                                })
                                              .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Tried on EF Core 2.0.3 and can't reproduce. Also consider upgrading to 2.1.3 - along with fixes it contains `GroupBy` optimizations (translate to SQL rather than executing client side as in the version you are using).

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev, thanks for the comment. I was able to compile and run successfully once I updated to the 2.1.3. Please drop this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution to this problem is to upgrade to EF Core 2.1.3 as mentioned by Ivan Stoev

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution and it works.

```
var analytics = await (_analyticsRepository.Query()
                .Where(x => x.PanelId.Equals(panelId, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                && DateTime.Compare(x.DateTime, new DateTime()) < 0))
            .GroupBy(x => x.DateTime.Date)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    DateTime = x.Key,
                    Max = x.Max(y => y.KiloWatt),
                    Min = x.Min(y => y.KiloWatt),
                    Avg = x.Sum(y => y.KiloWatt) / x.Count(),
                    Sum = x.Sum(y => y.KiloWatt)
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

using

```
 DateTimeField.Year +""+ DateTimeField.Month  //Use this
```

**instead of** using custom format for date like

```
 DateTimeField.ToString("yyyy - MM") //Don't use this
```

resolved the issue for me

btw my .net core version was 2.2.x